# What is difference between robots.txt, sitemap, robots meta tag, robots header tag?

Tags: web-crawlers, sitemap, robots.txt, meta-tags, http-headers

So I am trying to learn SEO and I am honestly confused and have following 8 questions.

1. Do I tell a bot not to visit a certain link through `X-Robots-Tag` or through `robot meta tag` or `robots.txt`?
2. Is it ok to include all 3 (robots.txt, robot meta tag, and X-Robots-Tag header) or I should always only provide 1?
3. Do I get penalized if I show same info in `X-Robots-Tag` and in `robots` meta tag and `robots.txt`?
4. Let's say for `/test1` my `robots.txt` says `Disallow` but my `robots meta tag` says `index, follow` and my `X-Robots-Tag` says `index, nofollow, noarchive`. Do I get penalized if those values are different?
5. Let's say for `/test1` my `robots.txt` says `Disallow` but my `robots` meta tag says `index, follow` and my `X-Robots-Tag` says `index,nofollow,noarchive`. Which rule will be followed by the bot? What is the importance here?
6. Let's say my `robots.txt` has a rule saying `Disallow: /` and `Allow: /link_one/link_two` and my `X-Robots-Tag` and `robot meta tag` for every link except `/link_one/link_two` says `nofollow,noindex,noarchive`. From what I understand bot will never get to `/link_one/link_two` since I prevented it from crawling at root level. Now if I provide a `sitemap.xml` in the `robots.txt` that has `/link_one/link_two` there, will it actually end up being crawled?
7. Will bot crawl into the directory provided by `sitemap.(xml/txt)` even though it is not accessible through home page or any pages following the home page?
8. And overall I would appreciate some clarification on what is the difference between `robots.txt`, `X-Robots-Tag` and `robot meta tag` and `sitemap.(xml/txt)`. To me they seem like they do the exact same thing.

I already saw that there are some questions that answer a small subset of what I asked. But I want the whole big explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `X-Robots-Tag` and `meta robots` are equivalent, `robots.txt` is different. The former is about indexing, while the latter is about crawling/visiting.

1. Tell bots not to visit a URL by using `robots.txt`.
2. Use only one of the three for each URL. Using both `X-Robots-Tag` and `meta robots` on a URL is redundant because they are equivalent, and using both `robots.txt` and either of the others for a URL can cause issues because `robots.txt` blocks crawling, and crawling is required for a bot to even see either of the other ones since they are document-level directives.
3. You don't get penalized, but it doesn't do anything more than just having a page in `robots.txt`. As I said in 2, `robots.txt` will block a page from crawling, but a bot would need to crawl the page to see either of the other 2, so it can't see them.
4. `robots.txt` prevents the bot from crawling and finding the other two.
5. `robots.txt` prevents the bot from crawling and finding the other two.
6. At least for Google, ["the most specific rule based on the length of the [path] entry trumps the less specific (shorter) rule."](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt) This means that your `robots.txt` file will allow crawling of `/link_one/link_two`, even though you disallow `/`.
7. See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox). Short answer is that if your site can't properly be crawled without the sitemap, it may run into SEO issues anyways. In other words, that could cause a problem.
8. `X-Robots-Tag` and `meta robots` are exactly equivalent, just one is a way to do it at the HTTP level, and the other is a way to do the same thing at the HTML level. They prevent indexing, they don't prevent crawling. Use them for pages you don't want in search results. In contrast, `robots.txt` prevents crawling, but not indexing. Use `robots.txt` for pages you don't want bots to waste time crawling, but that wouldn't be catastrophic if they showed up in search results (Google is [known to index URLs without crawling them](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7489871?hl=en) if they are considered important enough). If you use both `robots.txt` and one of the others, `robots.txt` will prevent the bot from visiting the page and even seeing the others, rendering them useless.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation!!! I find it very odd that google doesn't explain it as wonderfully as you just did!

Comment: @Quillion Welcome to SEO!