# Why does it cause issues to use robots.txt and a meta robots tag at the same time?

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, meta-tags, noindex, http-headers

It seems common wisdom that using `X-Robots-Tag`/`meta robots` with `robots.txt` to block a URL from being indexed "can cause issues", e.g.:

> Using both `X-Robots-Tag` and `meta robots` on a URL is redundant
> because they are equivalent, and using both `robots.txt` and either of
> the others for a URL can cause issues because `robots.txt` blocks
> crawling, and crawling is required for a bot to even see either of the
> other ones since they are document-level directives.
>
> Source: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/130710

However, I cannot see what the "issue" is. Suppose I have a URL `/foo.html` for which crawling is blocked using `robots.txt`. Then the bot will not crawl the page, but it might still be indexed if `foo.html` is followed from another site.  However, if we add a `meta robots` in `foo.html`, indexing will be blocked when the bot reaches the page from another site, independently of what happens to be in `robots.txt`.

Therefore, while it might be redundant to use both methods, I am not sure why doing so can cause `foo.html` to be indexed.

Comment: A related question I asked years ago: [Why do Google search results include pages disallowed in robots.txt?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24569/why-do-google-search-results-include-pages-disallowed-in-robots-txt)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `robots.txt` standard controls whether the bot can view `foo.html` under any circumstances. Just because the bot sees a link to it from a different site doesn't give the bot permission to sneak a peek at it!

> Suppose I have a URL `/foo.html` for which crawling is blocked using `robots.txt`. Then the bot will not crawl the page, but it might still be indexed if `foo.html` is followed from another site.

Correct.

> However, if we add a `meta robots` in `foo.html`, indexing will be blocked when the bot reaches the page from another site, independently of what happens to be in `robots.txt`.

There is a subtle misunderstanding here - the bot never actually reaches the page. What happens is the following:

1. The bot sees the link to `foo.html` on an external site.
2. The bot prepares to crawl `foo.html`, but first retrieves the `robots.txt` file from the domain on which `foo.html` is hosted, to make sure it is allowed to crawl `foo.html`.
3. The bot notices that crawling `foo.html` is prohibited, so it does not request `foo.html` at all. It is unable to see any of the contents of `foo.html`, including the `robots noindex` meta tag.
4. Unable to see whether the page has a `noindex` meta tag or not, the crawler makes its own decision for whether to index the page. It may decide to index the page, which it's allowed to do because it hasn't seen the `noindex` directive telling it not to index.
5. You end up with the situation where both `robots.txt` and `noindex` were used, but the page still gets indexed.

Comment: Thank you Maximillian Laumeister.  It also seems that steps 1-3 could also happen in principle when the bot sees a link to `foo.html` from a page on the current website, e.g., `index.html`, is that right?

Comment: @jII Yep! When the bot sees a link to a page whether it's an internal link or an external link, it will want to crawl that page. But it will consult `robots.txt` first (it [caches the `robots.txt` response for up to 24 hours](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_txt#caching)).